# How things work after deployement in Application Server?

Tags: jboss, websphere

Till now I have been coding in Java.

Wanted to know - **what happens after deployment in Application Server**

Suppose I deployed my EAR in AppServer (WebSphere or Jboss and Assuming Deployed Successfully!)

- EAR convert into tmp files.. etc etc
- How request picks some EAR or WAR in 100's of EARs or WARs in
  Application Server ?
- How application server look for datasources ?
- How Plugin-cfg.xml works.
  ..
  ..
  etc...etc..many more

Is there any document or anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a VERY VERY vague question, I would start here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp
with the instructions for WebSphere Application server v7 "Developing and deploying applications" section.

Comment: As roottop says, you got to clarify your question. If you are specific people would be able to help. Every vendor has their own documentation online which is a good starting point. The Infocenter as mentioned by rooftop is the place to go for WAS.

Answer (score 0):

I think the implementation of servers vary, so trying to put some basic principles.

- How request picks some EAR or WAR in 100's of EARs or WARs in Application Server ?

Application Server keeps a list of WAR and bind URL patterns /*  . If pattern matched, request goes to the application. Otherwise - error 404. Then application should be in memory, i.e. loaded by using specific classloader. After that methods like doGet called using reflection.

- How application server look for datasources?

  Application server collected all resources from xml description during startup  and changes on request. Next, return it on call. Here is example from [Tomcat source](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/tomcat/tc6.0.x/trunk/java/org/apache/naming/factory/DataSourceLinkFactory.java) of taking datasource from Hashtable environment.